# Changes to myApp.js files are reverted back to normal when the project is build - Cocos2dx

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I am trying to do some changes to my myApp.js file of coco2dx project for android in eclipse but I am not able to do it.

I am actually trying to change the default background image of my app. But when I run my project all the changes goes back to before values

For Eg: This is the default line wer we are setting  our background image

```
    this.sprite = cc.Sprite.create("res/HelloWorld.png");
```

I am changing it to the following line:

```
    this.sprite = cc.Sprite.create("res/CloseNormal.png");
```

But when I run my project CloseNormal.png goes back to HelloWorld.png

I am using:

- OS: Win7
- Cocos2d Ver: cocos2dx 2.2.2

Why is this happening. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the Resource folder permissions are not correct so using cygwin go to the Resources folder present in ur project.android folder of ur project and execute the following command:

```
chmod -R 777 *
```

Also refer to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2itbQceTQGI) link

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Re writing the permissions dint help I will again check out the tutorial in dat link which u hv provided and thanks :)